# nagios and SOAP support

Tags: linux, web-server, nagios, soap

Is there any plugin in Nagios that supports SOAP? I have a soap server and I would like
to send requests from nagios. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

A quick search on nagios exchange turned up [this](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Uncategorized/XML-SOAP-service-checking/details), although writing your own should be trivial.

Answer (score 0):

you should be able to easily do it with the built in http request job.  Its a bit tricky to get correct - but it is doable.

Check out this awesome link:
http://jbrazile.blogspot.com/2008/07/checkhttp-as-nagios-web-service-plugin.html

Comment: As an aside - we use this for THOUSANDS of monitors. I just got it working for my own use for the first time 20 minutes ago so I figured I would do a drive by and share.

Comment: Lone link is considered a poor answer (see [faq#deletion]) since it is meaningless by itself and **target resource is not guaranteed to be alive in the future**. [It would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.